# Silq Language - Custom quantum gate

Tags: quantum-gate, programming

Having a unitary matrix, is it possible to use it as a custom quantum gate using [Silq quantum programming language](https://silq.ethz.ch/)?

I found different documentation on the internet explaining how to do custom quantum gates using Cirq.

Is there a way to do the same using Silq?